# Prevent ModelBuilder Tools From Running if Published to ArcGIS Server

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server, modelbuilder

I'm looking for a way to prevent an ArcGIS ModelBuilder tool from running if it's been published to ArcGIS Server. Or, even better, for a way to prevent the tool from being published to Server in the first place.

Ideally, I'd like to find a way to keep the tools from running without a license. This has been discussed in [Copy protection via license file for ModelBuilder models?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/140751/copy-protection-via-license-file-for-modelbuilder-models) although no specific code is given. If licensing isn't possible, I'd like to keep these tools from being published to Server. Does anyone have ideas for Python coding (or a method directly in ModelBuilder) that could achieve this?

Comment: Could you instead perhaps limit publishing rights to ArcGIS Server in the first place, thus avoiding it being published?

Comment: My company sells customized ModelBuilder tools and we don't have control over our clients' installations of ArcGIS Server.  We'd like a programmatic way of limiting this in the tool itself. The closest suggestion I've found is using Python to detect if the tool is running on Server (http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62722/can-arcpy-detect-whether-its-running-in-desktop-or-server), and then render the tool inoperable. This might suffice but we'd prefer to keep the tools from publishing to Server in the first place.